# How can I annotate recursive types in TypeScript?

Tags: types, typescript

If I have a function like this:

```
function say(message: string) {
    alert(message);
    return say;
}
```

it has the interesting property that I can chain calls to it:

```
say("Hello,")("how")("are")("you?");
```

The compiler will generate a warning if I pass a number into the first call, but it will allow me to put numbers into subsequent calls.

```
say("Hello")(1)(2)(3)(4)
```

What type annotation do I need to add to the `say` function to make the compiler generate warnings when I pass in invalid types to the chained calls?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A type that references itself must have a name. For example,

```
interface OmegaString {
    (message: string): OmegaString;
}
```

then you can annotate `say` as an `OmegaString`,

```
function say(message: string): OmegaString {
    alert(message);
    return say;
}
```

then the following code will type-check.

```
say("Hello,")("how")("are")("you?");
```

but the following will not,

```
say("Hello")(1)(2)(3)(4)
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on WHY it must have a name?

Comment: @OldrichSvec You need a name to be able to refer to it, unless there was some special self-referencing type keyword, which IMO wouldn't be used often enough to be worth adding.

Comment: @OldrichSvec Peter is exactly right. A recursive type needs to be able to reference itself. Giving it a name allows it to reference itself.

Answer (score 0):

## Chainable method

When you are using a class instead of a function, you can use the `this` type to express the fact that a method returns the instance it was called on *(chaining methods)*.

Without `this`:

```
class StatusLogger {
    log(message: string): StatusLogger { ... }
}
// this works
new ErrorLogger().log('oh no!').log('something broke!').log(':-(');

class PrettyLogger extends StatusLogger {
    color(color: string): PrettyLogger { ... }
}
// this works
new PrettyLogger().color('green').log('status: ').log('ok');
// this does not!
new PrettyLogger().log('status: ').color('red').log('failed');
```

With `this`:

```
class StatusLogger {
    log(message: string): this { ... }
}
class PrettyLogger extends StatusLogger {
    color(color: string): this { ... }
}
// this works now!
new PrettyLogger().log('status:').color('green').log('works').log('yay');
```

## Chainable function

When a function is chainable you can type it with an interface:

```
function say(text: string): ChainableType { ... }
interface ChainableType {
    (text: string): ChainableType;
}
say('Hello')('World');
```

## Chainable function with properties/methods

If a function has other properties or methods (like `jQuery(str)` vs `jQuery.data(el)`), you can type the function itself as an interface:

```
interface SayWithVolume {
    (message: string): this;
    loud(): this;
    quiet(): this;
}

const say: SayWithVolume = ((message: string) => { ... }) as SayWithVolume;
say.loud = () => { ... };
say.quiet = () => { ... };

say('hello').quiet()('can you hear me?').loud()('hello from the other side');
```